# Should the mutex manipulation functions parameter be `volatile`?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I am working with custom embedded real-time OS having some home-brew threading and synchronization facility. The mutual exclusion is implemented in a way similar to the outlined below:

```
typedef int Mutex;
#define MUTEX_ACQUIRED    1
#define MUTEX_RELEASED    0

bool AquireMutex(Mutex* pMutex)
{
    bool Ret;
    // Assume atomic section here (implementation specific)
    if( *pMutex == MUTEX_RELEASED )
    {
         *pMutex = MUTEX_ACQUIRED;
         Ret = true;
    } 
    else
    {
         Ret = false;
    }
    // Atomic section end
    return Ret;
}

void ReleaseMutex(Mutex* pMutex)
{
    // Assume atomic section here (implementation specific)
    *pMutex = MUTEX_RELEASED;
    // end atomic section
}
```

Let's **assume** the two functions above are atomic (in the actual implementation they are, but the actual implementation is irrelevant for the question).

Each one of the threads are sharing some globally defined `m` and having the code similar to this:

```
extern Mutex m;
// .............
while (!AquireMutex(&m)) ;
// Do stuff
ReleaseMutex(&m);
```

The question is about the line:

```
while (!AquireMutex(&m)) ;
```

Will the `AquireMutex` actually be evaluated each iteration? Or the optimizer will just consider it as a constant since it won't see how `m` is changed? 
Should the `AquireMutex` be declared with a `volatile` qualifier instead:

```
bool AquireMutex(volatile Mutex* pMutex);
```

Comment: `extern Mutex m;` => `extern volatile Mutex m;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on whether the implementation of these functions is visible to the call site with the while loop. If it isn't (the call site only sees the declarations, definitions are in separate source files), then the `volatile` keyword will change nothing. Optimizer has absolutely no idea what this function does with the argument, whether it has side effects and so on, so each function call will be made.

On the other hand, if the functions to release and acquire the mutex are inline - so the **complete** implementation is visible on the call site - then indeed optimizer may "tweak" things up a little. The problem is in the "complete" word - even if the code you posted would be inline, the code which starts and ends critical section is probably not. And even if it is, it may use assembly statements which optimizer wouldn't understand.  Even if it's pure C, then it probably accesses some volatile memory-mapped registers. Any such piece of code (calling external function, assembly statements, accessing volatile memory) effectively prohibits optimizer from eliminating all the calls, as in that case it must assume that each call has side effects.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. I guess the optimizers can't work across the translation units these days...

Comment: @EugeneSh. - unless you use LTO (;

Comment: Which stands for... ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. - it's Link Time Optimization, which is supposedly able to do optimizations across translation units. But don't worry about this particular thing - if there is any operation with side effects (for example the critical section code with assembly instructions or accessing volatile memory-mapped registers), then you're still safe.

Comment: Cool.. looks like my compiler has to enable it explicitly and it is not.. but good to know